# Why is my Struct member changing when it isn't supposed to?

Tags: c

I've written this code in C where I want to increment the balance of a account if it is found with a matching string ID using the increaseBalance function, and although it does increment the balance value, it also changes the value of the structs ID as well. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ACCOUNT_NUM 1000
#define NAME_LEN 15
#define ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN 6
#define FILE_LEN 20

struct bank_account
{
    char owner_first_name[NAME_LEN], owner_last_name[NAME_LEN], account_num[ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN];
    int balance;

};
typedef struct bank_account Account;


void reg_new_acc(Account account_reg[], int *nrOfAccounts);
Account create_user(char owner_first_name[], char owner_last_name[], char account_num[]);
void accountManagement(Account account_reg[],int *nrOfAccounts);
void print_account(Account account_reg[], int *pNrOfAccounts);
int checkAccountNum(Account account_reg[],char account_num[], int *nrOfAccounts);

void increaseBalance(Account account_reg[], char accountNum[], int  amount, int *nrOfAccounts);

int main(void)
{
    Account account_reg[MAX_ACCOUNT_NUM];
    int nrOfAccounts = 0;
    char accountFile[FILE_LEN];
    //readFromFile(account_reg, &nrOfAccounts, accountFile);
    accountManagement(account_reg, &nrOfAccounts);


    return 0;
}

void accountManagement(Account account_reg[],int *nrOfAccounts)
{
    int choice = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("(1) Create New Account \n(2) Print All Accounts\n(3) Increment Account Balance\n");
        printf("\n\nEnter Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:

                reg_new_acc(account_reg, nrOfAccounts);
                break;

            case 2:
                print_account(account_reg, nrOfAccounts);
                break;
            case 3:
                    printf("Please Enter the Account Number: ");
                char accountNumber21[ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN];
                scanf("%126s", accountNumber21);

                printf("Please Enter the Amount: ");
                int amount=0;
                scanf("%d", &amount);
                increaseBalance(account_reg, accountNumber21,amount, nrOfAccounts);
                break;

           

        }

    } while ( choice != 9);
}


void reg_new_acc(Account account_reg[], int *nrOfAccounts)
{

    char owner_first_name[NAME_LEN], owner_last_name[NAME_LEN], account_num[ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN];

    while (*nrOfAccounts < MAX_ACCOUNT_NUM)
    {

        printf("\nRegistering User\n");
        printf("Please enter (6-dig) ID number (q for quiting): ");
        scanf("%s%*c", account_num);

        if (strcmp(account_num, "q") == 0)
        {
            printf("Avslutar\n");
            return ;
        }

        while(checkAccountNum(account_reg, account_num, nrOfAccounts)==0)
        {

            printf("This Already Exists\n");
            printf("Please Enter Again: ");
            scanf("%s%*c", account_num);

        }



        printf("Enter Name and Lastname: ");
        scanf(" %s",owner_first_name);
        scanf(" %s", owner_last_name);

        account_reg[*nrOfAccounts] = create_user(owner_first_name, owner_last_name, account_num);
        (*nrOfAccounts)++;



    }

}

int checkAccountNum(Account account_reg[],char account_num[], int *nrOfAccounts)
{

    if(strcmp(account_num, "q") == 0)
    {

        accountManagement(account_reg , nrOfAccounts);

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAccounts; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(account_num,account_reg[i].account_num) == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

Account create_user(char owner_first_name[], char owner_last_name[], char account_num[])
{

    Account account;
    strcpy(account.account_num, account_num);
    strcpy(account.owner_first_name, owner_first_name);
    strcpy(account.owner_last_name, owner_last_name);
    account.balance=0;
    return account;
}

void print_account(Account account_reg[], int *pNrOfAccounts)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nPrinting All Accounts\n");
    printf("ID\tFull Name\t\tBalance (kr)\n");
    printf("____________________________________________\n");
    for(i = 0; i < *pNrOfAccounts; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t\t%s\t%s\t\t%d\n\n", account_reg[i].account_num, account_reg[i].owner_first_name, account_reg[i].owner_last_name, account_reg[i].balance);
    }
}


void increaseBalance(Account account_reg[], char accountNum[], int  amount, int *nrOfAccounts)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < *nrOfAccounts; i++)
    {
       if(strcmp(accountNum,account_reg[i].account_num) == 0)
        {
            printf("In Increase");
            account_reg[i].balance+=amount;
        }
    }

}
```

If you run this code and after adding a user, try to increment the user account balance and then print out the user details, you will see that something strange has happened to the user ID number. I don't know why this is happening. Thank you for the time.

Comment: I get a crash just by giving `123456` as an account number.  You have allowed 6 characters but forgot about the terminating null.

Comment: Are you sure? I gave 123456 as ID and it worked

Comment: It only actually crashed for me when compiled with optimizations, or with AddressSanitizer. Nonetheless in C "it works" is a very poor indication of "it is correct".  Read the code and verify for yourself that it is wrong.

Comment: I am aware that my code is not clean at all, but I would really appreciate it if you helped me out with the account balance implementation for now.

Comment: Anyway practically all your `scanf`s have buffer overflows; they either don't limit the input length, or use the wrong limit.  I think the particular one spotted by xing is the cause of the crash at hand.  AddressSanitizer pointed directly to that line.  It's a great tool, you should check it out.

Comment: First thing I notice is you pass `int *nrOfAccounts` to functions that don't change it. It's not an error, but it's a potential for errors. Removing potential errors (including the scanf ones) might help uncover where thing are going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code, change the value for ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN to 7 to take care of the null terminator. This should fix your problem.

Remember that c string are null terminated. The null terminator also takes up some space and should be accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

"(6-dig) ID number" need 'char[7]' minimum, but ACCOUNT_NUM_LEN == 6

In function reg_new_acc(), after enter "123456" for account and "last" for owner_last_name, account variable contains "123456last".

In function create_user() strcpy(account.account_num, account_num) write "123456" to account.account_num, "last" to account.balance and '\0' cause 1-byte buffer overflow.

But operator 'account.balance=0' reset balance to 0 and account.account_num to "123456", because next byte write to '\0'.

After increaseBalance() account_reg[i].balance not 0. Therefore, the string account. account_num can get non-zero bytes after "123456" and will be printed as " 123456???".

P.S. Strictly speaking, in this program there is not a single correct operation with strings and not only with strings.

P.P.S. A good idea would be to use the latest versions of gcc or clang with stack-protector, mudflap, and _FORTIFY_SOURCE enabled, which provide some control over the use of arrays for storing strings.